# Trying to compile libgdx to html, but it cant clear the assets

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

Having trouble compiling my libgdx project to html.

Looking at the log I think the problem is;

```
Copying resources from ../android/assets to war/
C:\TomsProjects\MeshExplorerV2\html\..\android\assets
C:\TomsProjects\MeshExplorerV2\html\assets
    [ERROR] Generator     'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.preloader.PreloaderBundleGenerator' threw an exception while     rebinding 'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.preloader.PreloaderBundle'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't clean target path 'war\assets'
```

Now it strikes me as slightly odd the second line; As there was no html\assets folder.
The assets folder was in html\war\assets, like the last line complains about.

However, after creating a empty assets folder in html, and manually deleting the contents of html\war\assets I still get the same error.

Theres also a "html\webapp" directory without any assets folder. Not sure if there should be one.

I have tried cleaning/rebuilding from eclipse, as well as randomly also trying Gradle>>Refresh All.

Additionally, the Java version runs just fine.

Any pointers, thanks :)

Comment: I dont know if this will fix your problem, but I have noticed that in the past the html compiler has problems with assets not in sub folders (as in, if your assets are just in the folder assets, it has a hard time, but if they are in assets/data or something, it runs fine). I dont know if this is the problem you are having, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: well, it copys the assets from Android, which I understand is how its supposed to work. However, there is a mix within that. Some in android/assets some in android/assets/data. So maybe that has something to do with it.
*edit* nope, same thing;

C:\TomsProjects\MeshExplorerV2\html\.
../android/assets
Copying resources from ../android/assets to war/
C:\TomsProjects\MeshExplorerV2\html\..\android\assets
C:\TomsProjects\MeshExplorerV2\html\assets

Good idea though.

Comment: A solution that seems to work sometimes, is to manually remove the assets dir in the war directory. This might help if it hangs on the cant clean target error.

Comment: Also, close Eclipse before doing this. It might keep a lock on the assets dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not exactly reveling the route of the problem, I noticed it let me compile again as long as I restarted eclipse inbetween.
This infers some file-lock going on, possibly a server still running, allthough nothing but the gwt compile as triggered by me.
Still, restarting is a fine workaround for me as it only takes a minute or two.

*ah*

Pinned it down:  Close your FTP program when compiling - at least CoreFTP was locking the directory. Closing it works every time now.

Comment: Good find. Had a text editor open on a file in the assets dir, got the same error. Closing the editor fixed it. Didn't happen on Linux. Could be a Windows thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I was getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Generator 'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.preloader.PreloaderBundleGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.preloader.PreloaderBundle'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't clean target path 'war/assets'
```

All my files under the `html/war/assets` directory were read only, re-starting the IDE didn't help. To fix it I needed to change permissions `chmod -R 777 html/war/assets` (you probably dont need `777`).